# Excel- Not Allow Column to accept Duplicate data and length of text not more than 28 characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in Excel, for which i will have to put two data conditioning for it.

1. For a Range of Cells, it should not accept Duplicate Values.
2. For the same range of cells, it should not allow user to enter more than 28 Character of text length.
3. It can allow the cell to be Blank.

I tried by selecting the Cell Range and go to Data ->Data Validation->
Allow - Custom
Formula =  =AND(COUNTIF($B:$B,B5)=1,LEN(B2)<29)   But its not working.
For this formula, It is allowing be to enter duplicate data and also enter data more than 28 characters.

[image]

Comment: Is it giving an error? Where are you putting the validation? You look to `B5` for a duplicate, but `B2` for the length of a cell. Are you open to a VB solution?  Perhaps if you could post some sample data, it would help explain what you're looking to do/how.

Comment: '*its not working*' is insufficient.

Comment: For this formula, It is allowing be to enter duplicate data and also enter data more than 28 characters.

Comment: @BruceWayne, I have updated the screenshot with correct Cell reference. No VB pls.

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: On which cell you have placed this validation rule? If it is cell B16, it will work as expected.

Comment: It seems that, at least in Excel 2016, there is a bug such that if you paste (shift-insert) a value, it ignores the validation.  That is when I typed `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaaa`, I got the error but when I pasted it, it accepted it fine.  Could that be what you're experiencing?

Comment: @jkpieterse, I was trying to set data validation, by highlighting the entire column B and then enter the Data Validation formula. Filtering rules are not working for this scenario. It seems to be working only when Range of Cells are selected.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn, Yes Roger, this is also another problem i see. When we copy paste, the Formula is not getting carried over.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but the way I assigned the validation was to put the cursor in cell B1, highlight the entire column, and then put the formula in data validation using B1 (rather than, say, B16 as in your screenshot.)  I then put the cursor in other cells in column B (clearing the column highlighting) and verified that the validation was there and that it referenced the appropriate cell (e.g., for B16 the validation referenced B16.)

Comment: @RogerSinasohn, Yes Roger, your solution of entering on B1 works good. But, There is lot of possibility of performing copy paste. Is there a way to fix this issue while copying the content.

Comment: "Is there a way to fix this issue while copying the content." -- Are you referring to the problem of pasting a value into a cell bypasses the validation or not being able to copy the validation to a new cell?  For the former, I think you need to talk to Microsoft (though I have little hope they'll ever fix any bugs); for the latter, I think that, as long as the new cell is in the same column, it should pick up the validation because the validation was applied to the column as a whole. (I inserted a row as a test and the new cell had the same validation.)

Comment: @RogerSinasohn. I will be encountering more of scenarios where user will be copying and pasting to next cell.

Comment: You will have to catch pasting onto the validation cells yourself. One way: http://jkp-ads.com/articles/catchpaste.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hey you please write this formula,

=AND(COUNTIF(B$4:B$20,B4)=1,LEN(B4)<=28,ISNUMBER(B4+0))